# Defined method comes up undefined?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to recreate an example from *beginning ruby* by Peter Cooper.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :name

  def initilize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def talk
    puts "Meow!"
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def talk
    puts "Woof!"
  end
end

class Cow < Animal
  def talk
    puts "Moo!"
  end
end

class Sheep < Animal
  def talk
    puts "Bahhhh"
  end
end

animals = [Cat.new.initilize("Tiger"), Dog.new.initilize("Ginger"), Cow.new.initilize("Gretta"), Sheep.new.initilize("Sally")]

animals.each do |x|
  x.talk
end
```

Various attempts including calling the method separately do not seem to work. I'm not sure if the problem is with inheritance. Please help.

Comment: As a note when posting a question try and include the *exact* error message. If the stack trace indicates a line, describe which line produces the error.

Comment: What do you mean with "do not seem to work"? What´s the expected behaviour and what´s the current behaviour?

Comment: It wasn't returning the "talk" method of all the animals, it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. It's spelled `initialize`, not `initilize`. Methods with this name defined on classes are special because they return an instance of the class.
2. When you do something like this: `Cat.new.initilize("Tiger")` that is incorrect. You will never manually call the `initialize` method. It automatically gets run when you call `Cat.new("Tiger")` and has the arguments passed to it.

Comment: AHH thank you so much this fixed it. I guess step one to learning programing is working on my spelling thanks so much!

Comment: Paul Duca: if this answer addresses your issue, please accept it as answer.  It helps keep SO tidy.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing special about `initialize`. It is a method like any other. `initialize` returns whatever it returns, and you definitely can change its return value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag oh okay. removed the false assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong at couple of places.

1. You should change your method name from `initilize` to `initialize`.
2. Instead of doing `Cat.new.initilize("Tiger")`, you should do `Cat.new("Tiger")` to create the object.

After the code changes, you will get the desired results.

```
    animals = [Cat.new("Tiger"), Dog.new("Ginger"), Cow.new("Gretta"), Sheep.new("Sally")]

    animals.each {|x| puts x.talk}
```

will give

`Meow!`

`Woof!`

`Moo!`

`Bahhhh`

Comment: Thanks so much I appreciate the help! Need to improve my spelling before my programing skills can improve.